# Migrate Workspace from IBM RAD to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ibm-rad

I have some projects which are currently using IBM's RAD but because of cost cutting and License issues we have decided to use Eclipse. But when I check out the files from SVN and import them into Eclipse I don't see the Web App libraries and Ear libraries in the new workspace.
Is this got to do something with the project setup or am I missing something here.

Comment: RAD provides a superset of the plugins that are present in the Eclipse Java EE IDE. It should not be surprising that some functionality is absent, especially if you are looking for IBM server runtime environments. The base project hooks are in the `.project` XML files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but what you said is completely over my head. Yes, I do agree that i need to change something in the .project file but what? Can you help me with this.

Comment: Are you sure you have the basic Web Tools Platform installed? You would definitely need that. http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_install_WTP.3F

Comment: This is a rabbit-hole question - every answer will prompt new questions. What are the errors you are getting? What were the versions of RAD and the server you were targeting before? What versions are you targeting now? Give us the contents of the `.project` file.

Comment: The errors that i am getting are that the Action class in struts and Logger in log4j cannot be resolved to a type. I mean that it is not able to locate those jars. Earlier versions are IBM RAD 7 and web sphere 6.1. Now Eclipse Kepler and Websphere 8.5.

Comment: The contents of the .project are too long for me to paste here